# PHP download script shows error while opening from mobile

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a small website where user can download the mp3 files. The download script written in PHP & Codeigniter is

```
public function index($id)
    {

        $item = $this->music_m->get($id);
        if(count($item)){
            $path = $item->upload_path;

            if (file_exists($path)) {
                $item->noOfDownloads = $item->noOfDownloads + 1;
                $this->music_m->save($item, $id);
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($path);        
                exit;
            }else{
                echo "File doesnot exist";
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            echo "Requested music item doesn't exist in database";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

The URL of the download link is in the format http://yourdomain.com/download/63 where 63 is item id. 
Now when I click the link from desktop, it will download the file without any error. But when I click same link from smart phones(android) it gives me following error

```
ob_clean(): failed to delete buffer, no buffer to delete.
```

From some mobile, it gets downloaded but cann't open the file. Anybody knows where I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1.) you never open an output buffer, as far as I can see. See the _warning_ about a non existing buffer is correct. About you not being able to open the file: what does that really mean? What happens? What _is the content_ of that downloaded file? Most likely there is a warning _inside_ the downloaded file content which makes it invalid. Check that!

Comment: @arkascha: but in desktop it works well, I can download the file and open it. But in my android, it giving me the error

Comment: So, what is that meant to prove? _Maybe_ the desktop application you use is tolerant or whatever. The question is: _Did you check the files content_? Or do you think it is easier just to ask here so that someone does some magic and solves your problem?